# Mensagem de erro ao usar configurações do ESLINT em duas IDE diferentes

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

Olá pessoas a algum tempo estou enfrentando o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma determinada configuração do ESLINT, porém, trabalho com uma equipe e somente eu gosto de usar o intellij, e com a configurações de ESLINT que eles usam para VSCODE acaba disparando um erro no meu projeto quando uso a minha IDE, segue configurações ESLINT e erro!

```
{
    "env": {
        "commonjs": true,
        "es2020": true,
        "node": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "standard",
        "prettier",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "plugin:sonarjs/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 11
    },
    "rules": {
    }
}




Initialization error (ESLint). Unexpected token {
/home/rbalman/Documentos/projects/ccd/oem-ccd-customer-update/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js:421
    } catch {
```

Comment: Qual sua versão do Node.js e do ESLint?

Comment: node: v13.12.0
eslint: 7.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é mais simples, é necessário trocar a versão do interpretador dentro da IDE intellij da seguinte forma

Na caixa de diálogo Configurações / Preferências Ctrl + Alt + S, vá Languages and Frameworks | Node.js and NPM.

Depois selecionar a versão mais recente do node